# Post shell script and complete the build

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm

I am building and running node.js application through Jenkins.
I want to build and install all npm dependencies before starting the node.js. 
and then when everything succeeded I want to run "npm start" without stuck the building status (because when I am doing npm start and starting the node.js express server, the console is waiting)

So I have this build shell script:

```
sudo npm install
npm start
```

And also I tried using a post shell script plugin for Jenkins and use it only for the npm start, but the same thing happened to me, and the build is just waiting...

I hope that you are able to understand me :)

Comment: Are you saying that you want to allow the `npm start` command to run in the background, so that the shell isn't held up waiting for the process to quit?

Comment: @awarrier99 exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't needed to try something like this before, but you may be able to use a command such as `nohup` to allow the process to run in the background, for example: `nohup npm start &`. More info on the `nohup` command is available [here](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/unohup.htm)